# Different metrics for GridSearch and Keras: which one is actually returned

Tags: machine-learning, keras, grid-search

During GridSearchCV/RandomizedSearchCV we have different options to use for scoring, 'accuracy' being the most popular. However, in the case of unbalanced classes, such metrics as "f1_macro" are more appropriate. When we work with Keras, we can choose any metric in the `compile` line, however, no "f1_macro" or "f1_micro" is available. In case of using, let's say, "f1_macro" in GridSearch and "accuracy" in `.compile`, what score is actually returned after `.best_score_` is typed? Do we have to use the same metrics in both `create_model` and GridSearch or we can safely omit metrics in `compile`?

Thank you.